# The "RunMdaInstall" task failed unexpectedly. Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Whenever I try to run the emulator for the Blank Cordona App in Visual Studio this error occurs:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   MSB4018 The "RunMdaInstall" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException: The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RunMdaInstall.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() BlankCordovaApp5    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   287
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem:

These are the steps that worked for me.

1) Uninstall Node.Js from your system.

2) Re-Install the Latest version of Node.Js from their site [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

3) Then follow the steps given to re-install Cordova and Ionic from this site [Install Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

4) Clear Cordova cache from Visual Studio as Tools > Tools for Apache Cordova > Cordova Tool > Clear Cordova Cache.

5) Re-Start Visual Studio and try running your app

Hope this helps you,
:)

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on fixing similar problem (I built device app, and my exception was File Not Found) I can give you some tips to solve the problem.

### Empty cache

Go to Tools => Options => Tools for Apache Cordova => Cordova Tools => Clear Cordova Cache. If it doesn't help, before reinstalling entire tools (it didn't help me any way), try following:

### 1. Check versions:

node - v0.12.4 (run "`node -v`" in cmd)

If your version is higher, downgrade (uninstall node and install proper version from https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) Microsoft recommend to use the x86 version of Node.js

cordova - 5.0.0 (`npm install cordova@5.0.0 -g`)

npm - v2.10.1 (`npm install npm@2.10.1 -g`)

### 2. Check paths variables

Go to Control Panel => System and Security => System => Advanced system setting => Environment Variables

**Carefully** check the following parameters:
ANT_HOME; ADT_HOME; JAVA_HOME;

Look over here: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

If you are using TFS build server you also need:
ANDROID_HOME; MDAVSIXDIR; NODEJSDIR; NPMINSTALLDIR;

Check this link: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfs2013/

Googling a little will provide you default locations.
Also check, that you are using those variables in PATH (%{variable}% string in PATH). Add or update as needed. Don't forget to restart afterwards.

### 3. Check vs-tac module:

Go to npm modules directory (by default - %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules) and check for vs-tac over there. If it doesn't exists, install it:

```
npm install -g C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac
```

### 4. Enable "Diagnostic" verbosity

Last thing (or, actually first thing) you can (should) do

Go to Tools => Options => Project and Solutions => Build and Run and set verbosity to diagnostic. Or add /flp:verbosity="diagnostic" to build parameters ont TFS SERVER. Build again and look for errors, it can give you direction to finding the problem.

---

For android apps a lot of times I had problems with cordova plugins. Reinstalling android platform in the project always helped me:

```
cd {project dir}
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@3.7.1
```

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation of the aniversary update fixed the problem. No idea how that helps but it has.